# PaxExam OSGI Container and ServiceLookupException

Tags: maven, junit, osgi, pax-exam

I have built a very simple bundle which has zero dependencies and imports no packages.  Its only content is a CalculatorService interface and corresponding implementation class containing just a simple add(int a, int b) method.

I have created two PaxExam test containers for this bundle, one using a Karaf container, and the other an OSGI container.  The Karaf container tests work fine, but the OSGI test container does not.

To clarify a bit... if I remove the injection of the CalculatorService into the OSGI test container, and directly instantiate the CalculatorServiceImpl class in my JUnit test case, it works fine.  So the class from my simple bundle is visible to the OSGI test container.

Some questions:

- Is there something I am missing in my pom.xml files to make this work?
- Should I add more bundles to my OsgiTestClient.config() method?
- Other ideas on what is keeping is very stripped down example from working?

---

The following is the stack trace I get when trying to inject the CalculatorService into my PaxExam OSGI test container.

```
org.ops4j.pax.swissbox.tracker.ServiceLookupException: gave up waiting for service info.xyz.common.Calculator
    at org.ops4j.pax.swissbox.tracker.ServiceLookup.getService(ServiceLookup.java:199)
    at org.ops4j.pax.swissbox.tracker.ServiceLookup.getService(ServiceLookup.java:136)
    at org.ops4j.pax.exam.inject.internal.ServiceInjector.injectField(ServiceInjector.java:89)
    at org.ops4j.pax.exam.inject.internal.ServiceInjector.injectDeclaredFields(ServiceInjector.java:69)
    at org.ops4j.pax.exam.inject.internal.ServiceInjector.injectFields(ServiceInjector.java:61)
    at org.ops4j.pax.exam.invoker.junit.internal.ContainerTestRunner.createTest(ContainerTestRunner.java:61)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:266)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:263)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.ops4j.pax.exam.invoker.junit.internal.ContainerTestRunner.runChild(ContainerTestRunner.java:68)
    at org.ops4j.pax.exam.invoker.junit.internal.ContainerTestRunner.runChild(ContainerTestRunner.java:37)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:115)
    at org.ops4j.pax.exam.invoker.junit.internal.JUnitProbeInvoker.invokeViaJUnit(JUnitProbeInvoker.java:124)
    at org.ops4j.pax.exam.invoker.junit.internal.JUnitProbeInvoker.findAndInvoke(JUnitProbeInvoker.java:97)
    at org.ops4j.pax.exam.invoker.junit.internal.JUnitProbeInvoker.call(JUnitProbeInvoker.java:73)
    at org.ops4j.pax.exam.nat.internal.NativeTestContainer.call(NativeTestContainer.java:112)
    at org.ops4j.pax.exam.spi.reactors.AllConfinedStagedReactor.invoke(AllConfinedStagedReactor.java:84)
    at org.ops4j.pax.exam.junit.impl.ProbeRunner$2.evaluate(ProbeRunner.java:267)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.ops4j.pax.exam.junit.impl.ProbeRunner.run(ProbeRunner.java:98)
    at org.ops4j.pax.exam.junit.PaxExam.run(PaxExam.java:93)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
```

The pom.xml for my simple bundle containing the Calculator service is as follows:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>info.xyz</groupId>
    <artifactId>xyz-businessLogic</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1</version>
    <packaging>bundle</packaging>

    <dependencies>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <instructions>
                        <Bundle-SymbolicName>${project.artifactId}</Bundle-SymbolicName>
                        <Bundle-Version>${project.version}</Bundle-Version>
                        <Import-Package>
                        </Import-Package>
                        <Export-Package>
                            info.xyz.common,
                            info.xyz.common.impl
                        </Export-Package>
                    </instructions>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

It is clear there are zero dependencies to my simple bundle, and the packages containing the Calculator and CalculatorImpl files are exported.  Below is the blueprint.xml file for defining these services.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<blueprint default-activation="eager" xmlns="http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:jpa="http://aries.apache.org/xmlns/jpa/v1.0.0" xmlns:tx="http://aries.apache.org/xmlns/transactions/v1.0.0"

    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0 http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0 
            http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance 
            http://aries.apache.org/xmlns/jpa/v1.0.0 http://aries.apache.org/xmlns/jpa/v1.0.0 
            http://aries.apache.org/xmlns/transactions/v1.0.0 http://aries.apache.org/xmlns/transactions/v1.0.0">

    <bean id="calculatorService" class="info.xyz.common.impl.CalculatorImpl" />
    <service ref="calculatorService" interface="info.xyz.common.Calculator" />
</blueprint>
```

Next, the pom.xml for my PaxExam OSGI container is as follows:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>info.xyz</groupId>
    <artifactId>xyz-test-osgi</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1</version>

    <parent>
        <groupId>info.xyz</groupId>
        <artifactId>xyz</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1</version>
        <relativePath>../xyz</relativePath>
    </parent>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.ops4j.pax.exam</groupId>
            <artifactId>pax-exam-container-native</artifactId>
            <version>${pax.exam.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.ops4j.pax.exam</groupId>
            <artifactId>pax-exam-junit4</artifactId>
            <version>${pax.exam.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.ops4j.pax.exam</groupId>
            <artifactId>pax-exam-link-mvn</artifactId>
            <version>${pax.exam.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.ops4j.pax.url</groupId>
            <artifactId>pax-url-aether</artifactId>
            <version>${pax.url.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.ops4j.pax.exam</groupId>
            <artifactId>pax-exam</artifactId>
            <version>${pax.exam.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.ops4j.pax.exam</groupId>
            <artifactId>pax-exam-inject</artifactId>
            <version>${pax.exam.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.apache.felix.framework</artifactId>
            <version>5.4.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-core</artifactId>
            <version>${ch.qos.logback.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            <version>${ch.qos.logback.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
            <version>${javax.inject.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Testing target -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>info.xyz</groupId>
            <artifactId>xyz-businessLogic</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <!-- Needed if you use versionAsInProject() -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.servicemix.tooling</groupId>
                <artifactId>depends-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.3.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>generate-depends-file</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate-depends-file</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Finally, the OSGI Test class is given as follows:

```
package info.xyz.test.osgi;

import static org.ops4j.pax.exam.CoreOptions.junitBundles;
import static org.ops4j.pax.exam.CoreOptions.mavenBundle;
import info.xyz.common.Calculator;

import javax.inject.Inject;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.ops4j.pax.exam.Configuration;
import org.ops4j.pax.exam.Option;
import org.ops4j.pax.exam.ProbeBuilder;
import org.ops4j.pax.exam.TestProbeBuilder;
import org.ops4j.pax.exam.junit.PaxExam;
import org.ops4j.pax.exam.spi.reactors.ExamReactorStrategy;
import org.ops4j.pax.exam.spi.reactors.PerMethod;
import org.osgi.framework.Constants;

@RunWith(PaxExam.class)
@ExamReactorStrategy(PerMethod.class)
public class OsgiTestClient
{
    @Inject
    protected Calculator _calculator;

    @ProbeBuilder
    public TestProbeBuilder probeConfiguration(TestProbeBuilder probe)
    {
        System.out.println("TestProbeBuilder gets called");
        probe.setHeader(Constants.DYNAMICIMPORT_PACKAGE, "*");
        probe.setHeader(Constants.IMPORT_PACKAGE, "info.xyz.common");
        probe.setHeader(Constants.IMPORT_PACKAGE, "info.xyz.common.impl");
        return probe;
    }

    @Configuration
    public Option[] config()
    {
        return new Option[] {
                junitBundles(),
                mavenBundle().groupId("info.xyz").artifactId("xyz-businessLogic").versionAsInProject(),
        };
    }

    @Test
    public void testAdd()
    {
        info.xyz.common.impl.CalculatorImpl calculator = new info.xyz.common.impl.CalculatorImpl();
        int result = calculator.add(1, 2);
        System.out.println("--- testing: ");
    }
}
```

One final comment, if I comment out the code for injecting the CalculatorService, the code runs fine (as I am manually instantiating the CalculatorImpl class).  So my test container does have both compile-time and run-time visibility to the Calculator interface and implementation.  But injection of this service is not working.

And a final reminder, when I build a PaxExam Karaf Test Container, the injection of the Calculator service is successful and the test cases run fine.  The error is when running the PaxExam OSGI container described in this post.

Comment: Can you provide more information on how you register/publish the services in your Calculator sample? I mean do you use Declarative services or Blueprint or are you doing it with OSGi methods (ServiceTracker, registerServices...)

Comment: Good point... I've added the blueprint.xml to the original post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, then it is that the blueprint stack/libraries are not installed by default in native container (but they are in Karaf).

You need to add this deps to your test pom:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.aries</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.apache.aries.util</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.aries.proxy</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.apache.aries.proxy.api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.aries.proxy</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.apache.aries.proxy.impl</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.4</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.aries.blueprint</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.apache.aries.blueprint.api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.aries.blueprint</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.apache.aries.blueprint.core</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.aries.blueprint</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.apache.aries.blueprint.core.compatibility</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.aries.blueprint</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.apache.aries.blueprint.cm</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.5</version>
    </dependency>
```

And add the following bundles to your configuration in your test:

```
mavenBundle().groupId("org.apache.aries").artifactId("org.apache.aries.util").versionAsInProject(),
                    mavenBundle().groupId("org.apache.aries.proxy").artifactId("org.apache.aries.proxy.api").versionAsInProject(),
                    mavenBundle().groupId("org.apache.aries.proxy").artifactId("org.apache.aries.proxy.impl").versionAsInProject(),
                    mavenBundle().groupId("org.apache.aries.blueprint").artifactId("org.apache.aries.blueprint.api").versionAsInProject(),
                    mavenBundle().groupId("org.apache.aries.blueprint").artifactId("org.apache.aries.blueprint.cm").versionAsInProject(),
                    mavenBundle().groupId("org.apache.aries.blueprint").artifactId("org.apache.aries.blueprint.core").versionAsInProject(),
                    mavenBundle().groupId("org.apache.aries.blueprint").artifactId("org.apache.aries.blueprint.core.compatibility").versionAsInProject().noStart(),
```

That should make the trick!

Comment: That worked... thanks for your time, much appreciated.